# Angular cannot compile ngb-pagination error NG8002

Tags: angular, typescript, ngb-pagination

I'm working in an angular project int his project i'm using angular `ngb-pagination` with his property i first import `import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` in      `app-module.ts` and in the imports i import the `NgbModule` then in html part i use this

```
  <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="countAllUsers" [pageSize]="limitAllUsers" [(page)]="pageAllUsers" [maxSize]="5"
    [rotate]="true" [ellipses]="false" [boundaryLinks]="true" (pageChange)="loadAllUsersPage($event)"
    class="pagination-black pagination-on-game"></ngb-pagination>
```

but it usually comes with errors in this property `rotate` `ellipses` `boundaryLinks` and these are the reasons

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'rotate' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-pagination'.
1. If 'ngb-pagination' is an Angular component and it has 'rotate' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-pagination' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

21       [rotate]="true" [ellipses]="false" [boundaryLinks]="true" (pageChange)="loadAllUsersPage($event)"
```

i want some helps please and thank uuu

Comment: is your component resides  under `appModule`..?

Comment: no !!!!!!!!!!  it did not resides under the app-module

Comment: then pls import `NgbModule ` to the module where your component exists.

Comment: i imported the ngbModule in app module as i sad

Comment: I am facing this problem too. How you solved it Sir? I am using angular 12, trying to replicate table with sort, filter, pagination, etc